# Java Division error

Tags: java, division, integer-division

I have the following variables:

```
int first = 0;
int end = 0;
```

Declare in the public class.

Within a method:

```
double diff = end / first;
double finaldiff = 1 - diff;
```

The `end` variable on `System.out.println` is `527`, the `first` is `480`.

Why is the answer for diff coming out as `1`? It should be `1.097916667`, I thought using a `double` would enable me to calculate into decimals?

Comment: 0 / 0 is neither 1 nor 1.097916667...

Comment: Sorry, the end and first is gathered within a previous if statement.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: OP states: `The endyear variable on system.out.println is 527, the firstyear is 480.` As such the calculation is 527/480 which deos equal `1.097916666666667`. Not sure where you got 0/0 from.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl: From the fact that the OP specifies they're both 0...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: Well, it is class-level...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: I suppose all other members not having read past the first section are the ones down voting I guess. +1 from me anyway after reading the whole post.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl: I did read the whole question, evidently you read it too quickly (!) - "`endyear`" != "`end`", etc.  Anyway, I didn't downvote.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: You are correct in that the names don't match but I simply assumed they were the values though the OP referred to as the error was not related to a null division. But yes, you are correct and taking the post verbatim I see where you are coming from.

Comment: This is certainly ambiguous at _best_... I think I can understand what the OP is saying, but when I have to assume that `first = firstyear` and `end = endyear` happen before `diff = end / first`, I also have to wonder what else is going on that hasn't been stated. @FrançoisWahl

Comment: My apologies, i've corrected my explanation.

Comment: @LordTorgamus: I see what you saying. I think I just focused on the values being divided and that the issue was a rounding issue not a null division. You are correct in what you saying though that once you are assuming who knows what else is missing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dividing two `int`s will get you an `int`, which is then implicitly converted to `double`. Cast one to a `double` before the divison:

```
double diff = (double)end / first;
```

Comment: I had to wait ten minutes @lukecampbell, as does everyone when marking an answer correct.